# Subvariety $Y\subset X$ of codimension $1$ is locally defined by 1 equation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following theorem in Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry I*, Chap 2.3.1:

[image]

I'm trying to follow the indication of the proof, but I'm still stuck.

Here's my attempt: take an element $u\in k[X]$ which is zero on $Y$ but not zero on $X$ (this is possible because $Y\subsetneq X$). In particular $u\in\mathfrak{a}_{Y,x}\subset\mathcal{O}_x$, where:

$$\mathfrak{a}_{Y,x}:=\{f\in\mathcal{O}_x\mid f|_{U\cap Y}=0 \text{ for some neighbourhood }U\ni x\}$$

Since $\mathcal{O}_x$ is a UFD, there is $v\in\mathcal{O}_x$ irreducible which divides $u$ in $\mathcal{O}_x$. Let $U$ be the domain of definition of $v$ (by definition of $v$, $x\in U$).  I'm trying to prove that $\mathfrak{a}_{U\cap Y}=(h)\subset k[U]$.

Maybe I could do this by proving $\mathfrak{a}_{Y,x}=h\mathcal{O}_x$ and therefore $\mathfrak{a}_{U\cap Y}=\mathfrak{a}_{Y,x}\cap k[U]=(h)$. But I don't know how to prove that (or even if this is true).

Comment: One can start with $O_{X,x}$ and a local equation $h$, then "spread it out" over its open neiborhood. In the local ring $O_{X,x}$, $O_{Y,x}$ is defined by a single equation as all codimension 1 prime ideal in a UFD is principal.

Comment: @Youngsu please write this answer as an answer (instead of a comment).

Comment: @KReiser done as suggested. By the way, thank you for your answers (and comments). I enjoy reading them a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can start with $O_{,}$, and a local equation $h$, then "spread it out" over its open neighborhood. In the local ring $_{,}$, $_{,}$ is defined by a single equation as all codimension 1 prime ideal in a UFD is principal.

Comment: You mean $\mathfrak{a}_{Y,x}$ is defined by a single equation? By "codimension 1 prime ideal" you mean height 1 prime ideal? I'm having trouble justifying that $\mathfrak{a}_{Y,x}$ must be prime and must have height 1